# How to return value in text_fild on form from my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
#controller
class CalcController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @result = Calculator.calculate( params[:op],params[:a],params[:b])
    render "calc/index"
  end
end


#index.html.erb
<%= form_for :calc, url: { action: :new }, method: :post do |f|   %>
    <p>First num: <%= number_field_tag :a, params[:a] %></p>
    <p>Opration: <%= text_field_tag :op, params[:op]%></p>
    <p>Second num: <%= number_field_tag :b, params[:b] %></p>
    <%= f.submit 'Calculate!' %>
    <p>Result:<%= f.text_field :value => @result %></p>
<% end %>
```

> UPDATE(add more code of my project may be my trouble has solution)

```
#model
class Calculator

  def self.calculate(op, a, b)
    case op.to_s
      when "+"
        a.to_i + b.to_i
      when "-"
        a.to_i - b.to_i
      when "*"
        a.to_i * b.to_i
      when "/"
        a.to_i / b.to_i
      else
        "Exception !!!"
    end
  end
end
```

How to return value in this field

```
<p>Result:<%= f.text_field :value => @result %></p>
```

The code is working because I checked this

```
<p> = <%= @result %> </p>
```

and `@result` return `true`.
Thanks for help, in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> text_field(object_name, method, options = {})

Using `text_field` you need to pass the object_name as argument, and then to add the `value` option if you want to add a custom value. In your case the form isn't related to a model where to take the object name as one of its attribute, so you could use `text_field_tag`.

Try with:

```
<%= text_field_tag :result, @result %>
<!-- <input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="value for @result"> -->
```

See more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag).

Comment: No working, Showing D:/RoR/RubyCore/app/views/calc/index.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer, try `<%= text_field_tag :result, @result %>`

Comment: yes, working what different in this methods?text_field and text_field_tag ?Tell me please

Comment: The first one "returns an input tag of the “text” type tailored for accessing a specified attribute (identified by method) on an object assigned to the template" and `text_field_tag` "creates a standard text field".